# Editing an XML document

Tags: javascript, xml, web

I am new to JavaScript and need the ability to create, edit and export an XML document on the server side. I have seen different options on the Internet, but they do not suit me.

It seems that I found one suitable option with processing my XML file into JSON, and then back and then export it through another plugin, but maybe there is some way to make it easier?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow often closes questions like this as being "opinion-based": I can't say I like that, but the fact is that you're going to get a lot of answers that say "I would do it like this" rather than doing a proper objective analysis of your project requirements and constraints (which would require much more than two paragraphs to explain properly). Having said that (a) Going via JSON and back seems a really bad idea, (b) Look at high-level declarative tools for processing XML (such as XSLT and XQuery) in preference to low-level procedural languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across a similar problem. The solution turned out to be very simple. It is to use XML-Writer

In your project folder, first install it via the console

```
    npm install xml-writer
```

Next, first import it and create a new file to parse what's going on here:

```
    var XMLWriter = require ('xml-writer');
    xw = new XMLWriter;

    xw.startDocument ();
    xw.startElement ('root');
    xw.writeAttribute ('foo', 'value');
    xw.text ('Some content');
    xw.endDocument ();

    console.log (xw.toString ());
```

You can find more information [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-writer/v/1.7.0) and at the bottom of the page see the different code for each item. In this way, you can create, edit and export xml files. Good luck and if something is not clear, write!

*Additional*

You will need also fs module

```
    const fs = require("fs")
    const xmlParser = require("xml2json")
    const formatXml = require("xml-formatter")
```

Completed code:

```
    const fs = require("fs")
    const xmlParser = require("xml2json")
    const formatXml = require("xml-formatter")
    
    var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');
    xw = new XMLWriter;
    
    
    xw.startDocument();
    
    xw.startElement('root');
    
    
    xw.startElement('man');
    
    xw.writeElement('name', 'Sergio');
    xw.writeElement('adult', 'no');
    
    xw.endElement();
    
    xw.startElement('item');
    xw.writeElement('name', 'phone');
    xw.writeElement('price', '305.77');
    
    xw.endElement();
    
    xw.endDocument();
    
    
       const stringifiedXmlObj = JSON.stringify(xmlObj)
       const finalXml = xmlParser.toXml(stringifiedXmlObj)
    
    fs.writeFile("./datax.xml", formatXml(finalXml, { collapseContent: true }), function (err, result) {
       if (err) {
          console.log("Error")
       } else {
          console.log("Xml file successfully updated.")
       }
    })
    })
```

Comment: Okay. How do I export the file?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Completed my answer.

Comment: Okay. This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it turns out more conveniently than the options I saw before. Thanks!

Comment: That's incredibly low-level tedious code compared with doing it in XSLT or XQuery.